# Can we connect to Spark Master using Beeline

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, beeline

I have a Cassandra cluster set up with 6 nodes. I installed ***Spark*** and ***Thrift*** Servers so that we could connect to the Cassandra DB using Tableu. We have a set up of 1 Master Spark Node and 2 Worker Nodes.

I start the thrift server as below:

```
/usr/local/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh —-master spark://<spark-
master>:7077 –hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 10015 --jars 
/var/spark-connector/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar 
--driver-class-path /var/spark-connector/jars/spark-cassandra-
connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host="
<i.p1>,<i.p2>,<i.p3>,<i.p4>,<i.p5>,<i.p6>" --driver-memory 5G --
executor-memory 5G
```

I'm able to go to `http://spark-master:8080/` and view the Thrift Server that I just started.

Now, I'm connecting to beeline using:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://spark-master:10000
```

I can create views in spark for keyspaces in Cassandra and run queries but none of them are actually using the spark cluster. Meaning, I don't see any jobs in the Spark Master UI.

Am I missing something really basic here?
Can I even have beeline use the Spark Master?

Note: I have Thrift Server, Spark Master running on the same node.

Comment: can you try this connect command `!connect jdbc:hive2://spark-master:10000/;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice`

Comment: Hey. This is the error i get.  `Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://<spark-master>:10000/;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice: Could not create http connection to jdbc:hive2://<spark-master>7:10000/;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice. org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (state=08S01,code=0)`